# How to filter by a model instead of multiple parameters in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations, spring-annotations

I have an endpoint that lists the objects and queries it by the request params we add. Some values are optional. When the number of filtering values grows the code looks uglier. I am looking for a solution which looks good as well.

```
http://localhost:port/v1/actions?type=1&from=x&to=y&userId=z&adminId
```

And instead of having lots of parameters in my Controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
  public List<Actions> get(@RequestParam(value = "type") Optional<ActionType> actionType,
                             @RequestParam(value = "from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MMddyyyy") Optional<Date> from,
                             @RequestParam(value = "to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MMddyyyy") Optional<Date> to,
                             @RequestParam(value = "userId") Optional<UUID> userId,
                             @RequestParam(value = "adminId") UUID adminId) {
    return handler.getActions(type, from, to, userId, adminId);
```

Couldn't find any solution yet. Maybe something like this would be cool. Having a model and annotate them how the query parameters will be called:

```
public class QueryObject {
    @RequestParam(value = "type") Optional<ActionType> type;
    @RequestParam(value = "from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MMddyyyy") Optional<Date> from;
    @RequestParam(value = "to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MMddyyyy") Optional<Date> to;
     @RequestParam(value = "userId") Optional<UUID> userId;
     @RequestParam(value = "adminId") UUID adminId;

    //Getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Something like that would be cool:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public List<actions> get(
    QueryObject object,
    ) { return handler.getActions(object); }
```

If you have any suggestion? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the link. I am wondering about annotations. It says the model attribute is also overlaid with values from HTTP Servlet request parameters whose names match to field names. I am looking for a way to annotate fields in request model.

Comment: @EtibarHasanov have you tried the answer below.

Comment: @abdul, I saw your solution. However, I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

Such situations are quite common. So, it is always better to have only one query parameter which will take string value of the form" `key1::value1|key2::value2|key3::value3| ...`. Then for the controller method write a parser that will generate a map of your query params (keys) and their values. This is a best practice to process query parameters.

Here is an example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path="/search-products")
public ProductInfoListResponse searchProducts(@RequestParam(name = "filter", required = false) String filter) {

            final String[] QUERY_FILTER_KEYS = { "name", "type", "minCostPrice", "maxCostPrice" };

            Map<String, String> keyValueMap = getKeyValuePairFromFilter(filter, QUERY_FILTER_KEYS);

            for (String key : keyValueMap.keySet()) {
                 String value = keyValueMap.get(key);
                 //Process values here

                case "name":
                ...
                break;
                case "type":
                ...
                break;
            }
    }

public Map<String, String> getKeyValuePairFromFilter(final String filter, final String[] validFilterKeys) {

         final String QUERY_FILTER_PATTERN = "^(?:\\s*((?:[^\\:\\:\\|\\s]+\\s+)*[^\\:\\:\\|\\s]+)\\s*\\:\\:\\s*((?:[^\\:\\:\\|\\s]+\\s+)*[^\\:\\:\\|\\s]+)\\s*(?:\\|(?!\\s*$)|$))+$";

        final String QUERY_PARAM_PAIR_DELIMITER = "\\|";
        final String QUERY_PARAM_VALUE_DELIMITER = "::";

        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter)) {

            if (!filter.matches(QUERY_FILTER_PATTERN)) {

                throw BadRequestException.parameterInvalidExpectedValue("filter",
                        "key1::value1|key2::value2|key3::value3...");
            }

            String[] queryParamArray = filter.split(QUERY_PARAM_PAIR_DELIMITER);

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(queryParamArray)) {

                List<String> validQueryParamList = Arrays.asList(validFilterKeys);

                for (int i = 0; i < queryParamArray.length; i++) {

                    String queryParamPair = queryParamArray[i];

                    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(queryParamPair)) {
                        String[] queryParamPairArray = queryParamPair.split(QUERY_PARAM_VALUE_DELIMITER);

                        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(queryParamPairArray) && queryParamPairArray.length == 2) {
                            String key = queryParamPairArray[0].trim();
                            if (validQueryParamList.contains(key)) {
                                String valueText = queryParamPairArray[1].trim();
                                logger.debug("Adding key:value pair in the map: [{} : {}]", key, valueText);
                                map.put(key, valueText);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return map;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Amit, however, I am looking for more elegant solution.